# Can't change from NSDate in standard Master Detail template

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to change the example master detail code project that `XCode` provides so that instead of displaying `NSDates` in the master, it displays a list of strings.

If I leave this line in insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) it works fine...

```
newManagedObject.setValue(NSDate(), forKey: "timeStamp")
```

but if I change it to...

```
newManagedObject.setValue("hello", forKey: "timeStamp")
```

I get an error message of...

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>        reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "timeStamp";
>        desired type = NSDate; given type = Swift._NSContiguousString; value = hello.'

There are no references to `NSDate` anywhere in the source code that I can find, and I can't see any typing information in the storyboards, but clearly I am missing something.

Comment: Maybe in the code there is not, but in the .xcdatamodel property will be date, you could check it out.

Answer (score 2):

The `newManagedObject` is a managed object (aka database object) defined in the `xcdatamodeld` file - and `timestamp` is defined as a Date there. You have to change the type there.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 2):

If you've previously run the app, delete the app on your device.  Changes to the model require a migration (or a fresh install :D)

I've tested this out by creating a master/detail app.  The only two things I changed were:

- Change the data type of `timeStamp` from `String` from `Date`
- Changed `NSDate` to `"hello"` as per your question

That works as expected.

Comment: Glad you reminded me to delete the app. I would have wondered about that too!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the error message it seems that the property `timeStamp` in the `newManagedObject` class is defined as `NSDate` and not as a string. Check the class of `newManagedObject` object to verify that.